# Computing correlation of a matrix with its transpose

Tags: python, pandas, apply, correlation

I am trying to compute the correlation of a matrix(here, rows of dataframe) with its transpose using `apply`.

The following is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint
d = {'A': [1,0,3,0], 'B':[2,0,1,0], 'C':[0,0,8,0], 'D':[1,0,0,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_T = df.T  
corr = df.apply(lambda s: df_T.corrwith(s))
```

All the columns of correlation variable contains NaN entries. I'd
like to understand why NaN occurs.

Could someone explain?

Comment: Do you need `df.corr() ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.corr`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html):

```
print (df.corr())
          A         B         C         D
A  1.000000  0.492366  0.942809 -0.408248
B  0.492366  1.000000  0.174078  0.301511
C  0.942809  0.174078  1.000000 -0.577350
D -0.408248  0.301511 -0.577350  1.000000
```

If need your solution is necessary same index and columns values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d).set_index(df.columns)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
A  1  2  0  1
B  0  0  0  0
C  3  1  8  0
D  0  0  0  1

df_T = df.T  

corr = df.apply(lambda s: df_T.corrwith(s))
print (corr)
          A         B         C         D
A -0.866025 -0.426401 -0.816497  0.000000
B       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
C  0.993399  0.489116  0.936586 -0.486664
D -0.471405 -0.522233 -0.333333  0.577350
```

Comment: I tried to find the correlation matrix by removing the row with same values, since this leads to zero SD and NaN values . However, `df.loc[(df != df.iloc[0]).any(), :] `  this didn't work for removing rows with constant values. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Natasha - Do you need `df1 = df[~(df.nunique(axis=1) == 1)]` ?